# Download files with json

Tags: javascript, json, pdf

I need to download an attribute in json that has a url of a pdf and I need to download it, but I try to convert it but the body of the pdf generates it as html

THE FILE JSON :
"bulletins": [
{
"name": "Boletín mensual Julio 2021",
"type": "Mensuales",
"update": "2021-08-31 20:35",
"file": "https://saeadmin.sgc.gov.co/media/bulletin/Boletin_Informativo_No_0139_julio_2021_hq7KSVs.pdf"
},
]

Comment: Are you trying to download a PDF file or json? It would be good to see the input and expected output and see what code you wrote that is causing the error.

Comment: Your question is very confused, but if your code (which you've not shown us) is retrieving HTML from the URL (and you didn't accidentally fell on your keyboard and wrote a very complex bit of software which converts files between formats) then its the remote side wihich is returning HTML and not a PDF.

Comment: that is, I mean is how to download the attribute file as url that I have in the json file as pdf with javascript

Comment: I am looking to get the downloaded pdf file with javascript

Answer (score 0):

For simple download cases the system may have several means to download a file, Most desktop systems including windows 10 have the curl command. Thus for this usage write a small script snippet without any header request for the json data

Invoke in the relative OS method the single line `curl -O URL`

```
curl -O https://saeadmin.sgc.gov.co/media/bulletin/Boletin_Informativo_No_0139_julio_2021_hq7KSVs.pdf
```

That will automatically download the URL as a file which if you wish, and system supports it, you run that as a command to open in the viewer, just as if you had placed the source URL address into the browser.

[image]